# Error when Custom messages will be built

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I cannot build custom messages.

Target: ROS2 foxy

Created custom messages:

By refering https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Tutorials/Custom-ROS2-Interfaces/, I made srv file and tried to build it.

Error messages:

I found error messages as follows:

```
$ colcon build --symlink-install
Starting >>> tutorial_interfaces
--- stderr: tutorial_interfaces                         
CMake Error at /opt/ros/foxy/share/rosidl_adapter/cmake/rosidl_adapt_interfaces.cmake:60 (message):
  execute_process(/home/kentarou/.pyenv/shims/python3 -m rosidl_adapter
  --package-name tutorial_interfaces --arguments-file
  /home/kentarou/program/ros2/tmp/build/tutorial_interfaces/rosidl_adapter__arguments__tutorial_interfaces.json
  --output-dir
  /home/kentarou/program/ros2/tmp/build/tutorial_interfaces/rosidl_adapter/tutorial_interfaces
  --output-file
  /home/kentarou/program/ros2/tmp/build/tutorial_interfaces/rosidl_adapter/tutorial_interfaces.idls)
  returned error code 1:

  Traceback (most recent call last):

    File "/home/kentarou/.pyenv/versions/3.5.4/lib/python3.5/runpy.py", line 183, in _run_module_as_main
      mod_name, mod_spec, code = _get_module_details(mod_name, _Error)
    File "/home/kentarou/.pyenv/versions/3.5.4/lib/python3.5/runpy.py", line 142, in _get_module_details
      return _get_module_details(pkg_main_name, error)
    File "/home/kentarou/.pyenv/versions/3.5.4/lib/python3.5/runpy.py", line 109, in _get_module_details
      __import__(pkg_name)
    File "/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rosidl_adapter/__init__.py", line 32
      assert False, f"Unsupported interface type '{interface_file.suffix}'"
                                                                          ^

  SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/foxy/share/rosidl_cmake/cmake/rosidl_generate_interfaces.cmake:130 (rosidl_adapt_interfaces)
  CMakeLists.txt:25 (rosidl_generate_interfaces)


make: *** [Makefile:222: cmake_check_build_system] エラー 1 (<- sorry for japanese language, meaning error code 1)
---
Failed   <<< tutorial_interfaces [3.91s, exited with code 2]
                                
Summary: 0 packages finished [4.06s]
  1 package failed: tutorial_interfaces
  1 package had stderr output: tutorial_interfaces
---
```

Question:

Does the way to build custom messages change?
I could not build other project made on eloquent.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/355843/error-when-custom-messages-will-be-built/) by [kentarou](https://answers.ros.org/users/56126/kentarou/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2020-06-26

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Arne Nordmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/39498/arne-nordmann/) on 2021-11-05**:
I get the same issues now in a github action for rolling that did not have this issue before.
See https://github.com/micro-ROS/system_modes/runs/4114180941?check_suite_focus=true

Still not sure what to do, since the (python) environment is given by the ros-tooling actions and the github runners.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I fixed my problem.
I  installed pyenv and it caused the problem.
ROS2 foxy system seems to use python 3.8.2. But pyenv in ubuntu can treat only 3.8-dev. And under 3.6.6 was installed in my system.

I uninstalled pyenv and I could build srv project in tutorial.

---

Originally posted by [kentarou](https://answers.ros.org/users/56126/kentarou/) with karma: 26 on 2020-06-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Karl](https://answers.ros.org/users/67811/karl/) on 2021-11-05**:
You can mark your answer as solution then :)